# Resizing Window to larger size than Screen. (Unity Build)

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen

I am currently working on a project in which I will display my game on an extremely large resolution. At the moment i cant use the eventual setup, but I already want to see how well the game runs on that resolution. Whenever i try to create a build at that resolution it downgrades it to the max resolution of the screens i currently have connected to my computer and I can't rescale it any larger aswell. Is there any way i can work around this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are not very precise on how you're trying to change the resolution. [Screen.SetResolution](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html) should allow you to pass any resolution that you want, so long as it's not fullscreen.

Comment: Ok, sorry let me write it a bit more precise
Iam working on a project where i need a resolution of 15360x7560 in the final product. For this I have entered these values into Project Settings > Player > Resolution and Presentation > Resolution. When i run my build it automatically sets it to the maximum Screen size of the screens connected to my computer though and I cant resize it by any means. I have tried by dragging it bigger in window mode and setting the resolution with Screen.SetResolution. none of these work. Having further looked into it i think this may be a OS problem. ...

Comment: ... One solution may be to virtually set my screen to that size but my screens can not support this extreme resolution, except at extremely low herz rates (which my screens also do not support) from what i have tried. I would guess that it wont be a problem once i get the actual set up but i need this to work in order to test out the program before presenting it. Hope this clarifies it a bit better.

Comment: The most promising thing I have tried is DSR from Nvidea. But this allows me to only increase it to 4x the screen size, which is not enough. If anyone knows if I can set DSR to scale my screen resolution even further that would work.

Comment: Dunno what OS you are running, but I can also set the resolution in the project settings to 15360x7560 on my Linux machine, so long as it is set to windowed. Runs about as well as I would expect running an 8k application on my ancient machine.

Comment: I am using windows. I might use a virtual machine or get a laptop with linux then if that works. Thanks for checking it out!

Comment: It would be strange if Unity works better on Linux. If it's actually that you might wana take it up with the boys and girls at Mictosoft and Unity.

Comment: I think it may not be a Unity -> Windows specific problem but a general Windows problem.